# how to pass a member function with args as an argument to another member function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

The following example works with passing a member function pointer with no arguments. Can someone explain me how to do this with arguments? If it is possible can we also pass variable number of arguments?

```
class test {
public:
  typedef void (test::*check_fun_type)();
  //typedef void (test::*check_fun_type)(int);

  void mF1(check_fun_type ptr);
  void check1();
  void check2(int v1);
};

void test::check1() {
  std::cout << "check1" << std::endl;
}

void test::check2(int v1) {
  std::cout << "check2 " << v1 << std::endl;
}

void test::mF1(check_fun_type ptr) {
  (this->*ptr)();
}

int main() {
  test t1;
  t1.check1();
  t1.check2(2);
  t1.mF1(&test::check1);
  //t1.mF1((&test::check2)(2));
}
```

Comment: see also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: You could make `mF1` take an appropriate [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and pass in a little lambda that calls `check2(2)` when called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only pass the arguments when calling it. Such as:

```
void test::mF1(check_fun_type ptr) {
    (this->*ptr)(2);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use `std::bind` to invoke function with some of its parameters bound to arguments in advance, such as:

```
test t1;
auto f = std::bind(&test::check2, &t1, 2);
f();
```

For your case, you need to change the parameter type of `test::mF1` to `std::function`. Such as:

```
typedef std::function<void(test*)> check_fun_type;
```

and

```
void test::mF1(check_fun_type ptr) {
    ptr(this);
}

int main() {
    test t1;
    t1.mF1(std::bind(&test::check2, _1, 2));
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/l0nrGx)

Comment: `bind` is kind of a PITA, and in most cases just creating a little lambda wrapper is nicer. But `bind` does answer the question. Except you don't explain that the result can't be used as an actual member function pointer, and you need to change the interface of `mF1` to take a `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you could use

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void mFx(F ptr, Args... args)
{
    (this->*ptr)(args...);
}
```

to pass member function pointer of any type and variable number of arguments.
In C++98 similar functionality can be achieved by overloading methods for each number of arguments

```
template <class F>
void mFx(F ptr)
{
    (this->*ptr)();
}

template <class F, class A1>
void mFx(F ptr, A1 a1)
{
    (this->*ptr)(a1);
}

template <class F, class A1, class A2>
void mFx(F ptr, A1 a1, A2 a2)
{
    (this->*ptr)(a1, a2);
}
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting, but I don't think this is really what the OP is asking. I believe they want to fix the argument at the call site, turning a function that is called with 1 argument into a function that is called with none (modulo implicit `this`).